# Chrome - Lines Between Sections - Relative Positioning

Tags: css, html, google-chrome

I have layered a page with the header, article and footer sections as relative position to stack inside a wrapper. And are in the correct positions.

However, I have noticed that Chrome has a white line (spacing between sections ?) and tried disabling shadows and also to absolute by changing the values using the CSS inspector in Chrome with the same result.

In Edge and Firefox, there is no line.

Link is here: 
http://zen8.prosoftwareuk.co.uk/p/1863/home

Screen shots:
Chrome:
[image]

Edge:
[image]

Firefox:
[image]

Any way to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how this happens, but adding the same background-color to its containers would make the line invisible. Hope this helps

```
article.screen-width {
    background: rgb(153, 153, 153);
}

.window_scale {
    background: rgb(153, 153, 153);
}
```

Comment: Update: Safari does the same effect as Chrome

Comment: You beat me by a few seconds, but I think you're right. The source of the problem is a bit of a mystery, but making the container background the same color gray eliminates the lines. Just applying the gray to `.window_scale` seems to work.

Comment: I found out by removing the transform: scale(ratio) it removes the lines in Chrome on window_scale class. It is a requirement that I need the website to zoom.